# Types of types with templates?

Tags: c++

```
template<???>    
struct Container{
  T t;
  M<T> v;
}
```

where `Container<vector<int>>` should generate

```
struct Container{
 int t;
 vector<int> v;
}
```

Can I express this with templates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
template<typename T, template <typename, typename> class M>
struct Container {
    T t;
    M<T,std::allocator<T>> v;
};
```

Use with:

```
Container<int,std::vector>
```

Alternately:

```
template <typename C>
struct Container {
    typename C::value_type t;
    C v;
};
```

And use with:

```
Container<std::vector<int>>
```

Comment: But it won't work for `std:array<T,N>`, `std::map<K,T,Compare,Alloc>`, etc. etc.

Comment: @Useless: Hence the alternate form.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the templates simple or you will get a headache.

```
template<class CONTAINER>
struct Container
{
    typedef CONTAINER container_type;
    typedef typename container_type::value_type value_type;

    value_type t;
    container_type v;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a couple of ways. You can either require your type parameter to be a container with `value_type` defined:

```
template <typename T>    
struct Container {
  typename T::value_type t;
  T v;
};
```

(which will fail to compile if `T` isn't some class with the `value_type` typedef), or you can do something more elaborate. I'd go with requiring `value_type` to be defined, if possible.